# Exception Handler Not Working with `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, kotlin

My last Java/Spring experience was around four years ago. I've started learning Spring Boot with Kotlin.

I've created a RESTful web service (in Kotlin) like this, and it works fine:

```
@RequestMapping("/authorization")
public fun authorization(@RequestParam(value = "network-type", defaultValue = "Facebook") name: String,
                         @RequestParam(value = "oauth-token") oauthToken: String,
                         @RequestParam(value = "oauth-token-secret",
                                 required = false) oauthTokenSecret: String?): Authorization
{
    //TODO: Handle other social network types
    return facebookAuth.authorization(oauthToken)
}
```

Now I'm having trouble adding an exception handler for when the `facebookAuth` throws UnauthorizedException.

**What I've tried:**

- I tried registering an exception handler method on the controller.
- I've tried creating cross-cutting exception advisor class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`

In both cases, the exception is not mapped, and instead I get:

## Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Sun Oct 25 16:00:43 PHT 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Invalid OAuth access token.
```

**Question:**

What is the correct way with Spring Boot to register an exception handler that can return a serialized `ErrorResponse` object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by registering the following exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler()
{

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable::class)
    @ResponseBody
    internal fun onException(ex: Throwable): ErrorResponse
    {
        //TODO: Replace instanceof with polymorphism
        var responseCode = ResponseCode.VAMPServiceError
        if (ex is UnauthorizedException) {
            responseCode = ResponseCode.VAMPUnauthorized
        }

        val errorResponse = ErrorResponse(
            response = ResponseHeader(responseCode, ex.message))
        return errorResponse
    }
}
```

This was based on another StackOverflow anwer (which I've lost). In that answer the answer suggested to include `@EnableWebMVC` on the handler. I found that this wasn't necessary in my case"